# @Value not Injecting ANY value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, variables, spring-annotations

I'm learning how to create a RESTful API with Springboot, and the @Value tag is not injecting values from application.properties, nor is it injecting values specified in the tag itself. I have my project structured as such:

- api

  - config
  - controllers
  - model
  - services
  - SpringApplication.java
- resources

  - application.properties

Strangely, this behavior only seems to occur within files located in my "services" folder. The `@Value` tag works as expected in files located in my "controllers" folder. Below are examples of what I am doing:

```
@Value("${var}")
String variable
```

"var" is defined in application.properties as `var=some_string`but *variable* is still initialized as 'null'

```
@Value("I am directly assigning a value to this variable, but it still comes out null")
String variable
```

I believe I am using the correct import: `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value`.
At first I just thought the "services" folder was blind to the directory where application.properties is located, but after trying to directly inject values, I'm not so sure what to think.

### Edit

All of the classes in the services folder are annotated with `@Service` and nothing else. Below is what the class looks like. I've opted to leave out implementations of the methods, other variables, and irrelevant imports. The code/methods all work as expected when hard-coding the variables. My focus is the @Value tag.

```
package myapi.api.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${var}")
    String variable;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return new ArrayList<Data>();
    }

    public void postData() {

    }
```

### Edit 2

Below is the APIController class, stored in the "controllers" folder. Again, I've opted to leave out irrelevant methods/imports/variables. I would also like to note, that the `@Value` tag works as expected in this class.

```
package myapi.api.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import myapi.api.services.MyService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class APIController {

 @Autowired
 private final static MyService myService = new MyService();

 @GetMapping("/getdata")
 public List<Data> getData() {
     return myService.getData();
   }
}
```

Comment: please show the enclosing class of `variable` is it a spring component annotated or instantiated correctly thus registering it as a bean?

Comment: can you paste the entire class where you are `@Inject` or `@Autowire` `MyService`? (the class with the injection point)

Comment: The class is annotated with the `@Service` tag. In the edit I made, I opted to exclude details about my code that I consider irrelevant to the problem. @Lino

Comment: I've just made an edit and included the APIController class. Thanks! @JonathanS.Fisher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private final static MyService myService = new MyService();
```

Three issues:

First, you cannot have a `new` operator. Spring controls the lifecycle of your class instances. It will call `new` for you in the background. Remove the entire new operator stanza.

Next: your your field cannot be `final`. After construction of the class, Spring will need to modify that field with a proxy. Remove the `final` declaration;

Finally: your field cannot be `static`. `static` variables have a certain lifecycle with the JVM, and you need to let the Spring framework manage your lifecycle. remove the static operator.

The correct declaration should be:

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;
```

Comment: Right, right, right! That sorted me out! Many thanks!